# Is it possible to join a modded Terraria game without downloading mods?

Tags: terraria

I want to join someone in a modded playthrough, but I'm not sure if I need to download the mod. Should I download it or just join straight up?

Answer (score 5):

You always need the mod used to join a modded playthrough. There is no way to join without it, you will get kicked out for not having it by the game.